# How can I programmatically add a link that redirects users to a parent site?

Tags: 8

I'm currently building a Drupal multi-site and I'm trying to figure out if there is a way to add a link programmatically that redirects to the Drupal parent site.

Using `{{ url('<front>') }}` only redirects to the home page of the multi-site. I could just add it manually but I was searching to make it dynamic instead.

Comment: One easy way is for all sites to extend a base theme from the parent, and the parent theme theme file define a page level variable to output somewhere. That's just one method.

Comment: @Kevin sorry for ignorance when you meant extend a base theme, do you also mean inherit a base theme for the parent site?

Comment: Yes, basically. You could alternatively do it as a theme setting or custom module that exports config, but you'd have to enter that on each site, which is why this occurred to me first.

Comment: @Kevin thanks for responding. Do you have any reference or source materials I can read upon? I'm still new to Drupal and also the multi-site levels

Comment: The core docs discuss how to inherit a theme... I don't want to solution it for you because I don't know all the circumstances of your project.